# How to avoid false separators in csv / XML

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, csv

I've been trying to understand how XML and CSV parsing work, without actually writing any code yet. I might have to parse a .csv file in the ongoing project and I'd like to be ready. (I'll have to convert them to .ofx files)

I'm also aware there's probably a thousand XLM and csv parsers out there, so I'm more curious than I am worried. I intend on using the `XMLReader` that I believe microsoft provides.

Let's say I have the following .csv file

> 02/02/2016 ; myfirstname ; mylastname ; somefield ; 321654 ; commentary ; blabla

Sometimes a field will be missing. Which means, for the sake of the example, that the lastname isn't mandatory, and somefield could be right after the first name.

My questions are :

- How do I avoid the confusion between somefield and lastname?

I could count the total number of fields, but in my situation two are optional, if there is only one missing, I can't be sure which one it is.

- How do I avoid false "tags"? I mean, if the user first comment includes a `;`, how can I be sure it's a part of his comment and not the start of the following tag?

Again, I could count the remaining fields and find out where I am, but that excludes the optional fields problem.

My questions also apply to XML, what can I do if the user starts writing XML in his form ? Wether I decide to export the form as .csv or .xml, there can be trouble.

Right now I'm on the assumption that the c# Xml reader/parser are awesome enough to deal with it ; and if they are, I'm really curious on the how.

Comment: Missing fields should still have the semicolon with no data.  CSV is usually consider separated by commas.  You have a file with a semicolon delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the CSV/XML data has been exported properly, none of this will be a problem.  Missing fields will be handled by repeated separators:

> 02/02/2016;myfirstname;;somefield

Semi-colons within a field will normally be handled by quoting:

> 02/02/2016;"myfirst;name";

Quotes are escaped within a string:

> 02/02/2016;"my""first""name";

With XML it's even less of an issue since the tags or attributes will all have names.

If your CSV data is NOT well-formed, then you have a much bigger problem, as it may be impossible to distinguish missing fields and non-quoted separators.

Comment: I understand, this solves everything, and the .csv I'm getting isn't actually formed like that. But even though this is a "big problem", it's easily solved.
Thanks man, but now I realize my question is a bit senseless since I was asking it under false assumptions (that my files where fine)

Comment: For completeness you might want to add: seperators should not be surrounded with spaces (some parsers can have problems with that). Quotes inside a quoted field have to be escaped with another quote - for example: `27";monitor` would become `"27"";monitor"`.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt

**How do I avoid the confusion between somefield and lastname?**

There is no way to do this without change the logic of file. For example: when "mylastname" is empty You may have a "" value, empty string or like this ;;

**How do I avoid false "tags"? I mean, if the user first comment includes a ;, how can I be sure it's a part of his comment and not the start of the following tag?**

It is simple you have to file like this:

; - separor of columns

"" - delimetr of columns

> value;value;"value;;;;value";value

To split this only for separtor ; without the separator in "" this code do this is tested and compiled

```
public static string[] SplitWithDelimeter(this string line, char separator, char checkSeparator, bool eraseCheckSeparator)
        {
            var separatorsIndexes = new List<int>();

            var open = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] == checkSeparator)
                {
                    open = !open;
                }

                if (!open && line[i] == separator )
                {
                    separatorsIndexes.Add(i);
                }
            }

            separatorsIndexes.Add(line.Length);

            var result = new string[separatorsIndexes.Count];

            var first = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < separatorsIndexes.Count; j++)
            {
                var tempLine = line.Substring(first, separatorsIndexes[j] - first);

                result[j] = eraseCheckSeparator ? tempLine.Replace(checkSeparator, ' ').Trim() : tempLine;

                first = separatorsIndexes[j] + 1;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Return would be:

value

value

"value;;;;value"

value

Answer (score 0):

1. How do I avoid false "tags"? String values should be quoted if the (can) contain separator characters. If you create the CSV file, quote and unquote all string values.
2. How do I avoid the confusion between somefield and lastname? No general solution for this, all case must be handled one by one. Can a general algorithm decide wheather first name or last name is missing? No.
   If you know what field(s) can be omitted, you can write an "intelligent" handling.

Use XML and all of your problem will be solved.